# ‘noun + likely to + verb’ and ‘likely to + verb + noun’

Tags: grammaticality, adjective-phrases

Are the following sentences grammatically correct? If yes, which one does sound more idiomatic?

- Modularization by design decision likely to change.
- Modularization by likely to change design decision.

The meaning that I want to convey is the following. In a system, all design decisions can be changed, but it is impossible that they are equally *easy* to change. So when designing a system, the designer should identify the design decisions that are *likely* to change and make them easy to change by confining them in single modules. This is a criterion, known as *information hiding*, for decomposing a system into modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/576925/noun-likely-to-verb-and-likely-to-verb-noun#comment1439051_576925), my understanding is that the intended meaning is:

> We want to organize the software architecture into modules by separating the concerns of various design decisions, all of which are subject to change (so that such changes affect as small a scope as possible).

If that's true, the first option is unclear: "likely to change" could modify either "modularization" or "design decision."

The second option seems to attempt the right meaning, but it really ought to use hyphens: "Modularization by likely-to-change design decision." Which is still pretty unwieldy and unclear.

If it's okay to use full sentences, I would suggest something like: "Modularization aligns with design decisions which are likely to change."

Comment: Yes that is the intended meaning. Would the sentence ‘Modularization based on design decisions which are likely to change.’ be clear?

Comment: @Maggyero Yes, that's the best yet!

Comment: What about ‘Modularization based on likely-to-change design decisions.’?

Comment: Google hits: "modularization by": 17,000 results; "modularization based on": 13,500 results; "modularization on the basis of": 5,490 results; "modularization according to": 2,070 results; "modularization aligns with": 1 result.